# Android listener for changing of ring volume and other settings?

Tags: android, listener, volume

I was wondering if there is a way to know if the user has changed the ring volume or changes any settings on the phone? I'm trying to create an app that has that capability: detects whether the user changed the ring volume or changed any settings on his/her own device?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue. I had to limit the max volume in an app, so this is what I did  (audio is instance of AudioManager):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        if(audio != null){
            int curVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            int maxVolume = Preferences.getDefaultMaxVolume(Main.this);
            if(curVolume > maxVolume) audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, 0);
        }

    } 

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can simply use the setStreamVolume() method to change progrmatically the volume, if needed...